# Is there a ranking of US national parks based on their Google Review rating?

Tags: usa, national-parks, outdoor-activities

While planning a holiday in the US and intending to visit national parks, it would be nice to see a ranking of US national parks based on their Google Review rating. That way one could decide on which park to visit. Does such a ranking exist?

Comment: Have you? Or Googled to see if someone else did?

Comment: How accurate could something like that be?  Parks like Yellowstone, Yosemite, etc would have hundreds of reviews, parks like Kobuk Valley or American Samoa would be lucky to have one.

Comment: I tried googling and it didn't turn up any relevant link

Comment: @Tom I understand your point but lets not let it distract from the question

Comment: Yeah, I did this last night. Was totally bored. Not gonna share it with anyone, though, I keep it in a private document on my own computer.

Comment: I have edited this, to reduce the chance of this being closed as off topic. OP, I hope you don't mind. Voting to leave open.

Comment: I don't think the question as originally asked is realistic, or that the edit reflects the author's intent. As such, I'm not going to vote to reopen at this time. I will wait to see if the author comes back to clarify his question.

Comment: WTF is unclear about this Q? I have voted to reopen! When I google "Yellowstone Park" google shows me a 4.6/5 rating and I guess one could do the same for any other national park and then make a ranking. What is unclear about that? If you think it is unrealistic or inaccurate, answer as far as such, but that is no reason to close a Q as unclear!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think the edit fully reflects the OPs intention, and even the original version seemed clear enough for me. As it currently stands, I find it a pity this question is closed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Unclear? Seriously?  When I saw the close-votes, I had assumed the reason was "off-topic",  not "unclear". The question is clear as day,  IMO. (I don't think it's off-topic, either,  BTW.)

Comment: Any particular reason to choose Google's review data (not a criticism, just curious0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just went through and looked up all the ratings. Below is the list of National Parks, sorted by rating and then by number of reviews as of September 1, 2016.

```
National Park       Rating    Reviews
-------------------------------------
Badlands             4.9       549
Virgin Islands       4.9        94
Arches               4.8       851
Sequoia              4.8       805
Acadia               4.8       729
Carlsbad Caverns     4.8       466
Rocky Mountain       4.8       463
Grand Teton          4.8       263
Olympic              4.8       246
Dry Tortugas         4.8       177
Black Canyon of      4.8       133
  the Gunnison
Grand Canyon         4.7      2129
Yosemite             4.7      2041
Zion                 4.7      1591
Bryce Canyon         4.7       994
Mount Rainier        4.7       743
Crater Lake          4.7       707
Redwood              4.7       515
Cuyahoga Valley      4.7       407
Big Bend             4.7       232
Lassen Volcanic      4.7       223
Canyonlands          4.7       197
Theodore Roosevelt   4.7       180
Kings Canyon         4.7       128
Great Basin          4.7        86
Katmai               4.7        24
Yellowstone          4.6      1880
Shenandoah           4.6       643
Great Smoky          4.6       581
   Mountains
Joshua Tree          4.6       417
Haleakala            4.6       404
Great Sand Dunes     4.6       306
Pinnacles            4.6       219
Saguaro              4.6       200
Guadalupe Mountains  4.6        84
Congaree             4.6        74
Death Valley         4.5       637
Hawaii Volcanoes     4.5       528
Mammoth Cave         4.5       526
Capitol Reef         4.5       209
Wind Cave            4.5       112
Isle Royale          4.5        70
North Cascades       4.5        53
Kenai Fjords         4.5        38
Lake Clark           4.5        13
Channel Islands      4.5         9
Everglades           4.4       339
Hot Springs          4.4       232
Biscayne             4.4       124
Glacier Bay          4.4        54
Gates of the Arctic  4.4        35
American Samoa       4.4        13
Petrified Forest     4.3       302
Voyageurs            4.3        24
Kobuk Valley         4.1        14
Wrangell - St. Elias   4        18
Mesa Verde             4      unknown
Glacier              3.7*      383
Denali               3.7*      175
```

<sub>* Glacier and Denali National Parks both stated 3.8 with no review count on the Google homepage, but 3.7 and review count when looking on Google Maps. I do not know why there is a discrepancy, but all other ratings are from the Google homepage.</sub>

Comment: By the way, why is the review count for Mesa Verde unknown?

Comment: @Fiksdal it just doesn't list it when searched on both the [homepage](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=mesa%20verde%20national%20park) and [maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mesa+Verde+National+Park/@37.2427781,-108.6055413,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x873960bf2ed7711f:0x79f695a21bf61863!8m2!3d37.2308729!4d-108.4618335?hl=en). Glacier and Denali both don't list it on the homepage but do when in Google Maps.

Comment: @clcto Alright.